# what are steps to Programmatically take screenshot using framebuffer in android

Tags: android, linux, screenshot

My Device is rooted and I want to Programmatically take screenshot. I am trying to do it using framebuffer
like this.

```
$ /system/bin/cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /mnt/sdcard/screenshot.bin
/system/bin/cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /mnt/sdcard/screenshot.bin
```

**screenshot.bin** file has been successfully created on sdcard and its file size is 4800KB

Can any one tell what should I do next to get Image.

Please help!! sorry for my poor English.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Don't think too much... Accept previous helpful answers

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Please provide the link if you Know. As I didn't get any useful link which can help me to complete my task