# Why program still don't take screenshot after getting "su"?

Tags: android, screenshot, root, framebuffer, su

I push the button and program get SU, but png file is 0 bytes weight. Logcat says

> Permission denied: can't read framebuffer pid=12844 uid=10087.

So why that's so. My phone is rooted, program already get su. What's wrong?

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                    Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/s.png");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: found [working code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15208354/2177105). He's answer realy helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this one, it should have better support:

```
@Override
public void onCLick(View v)
 try{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

    os.writeBytes("/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/s.png\n");
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    process.waitFor();
 } catch (Exception e){
 };
};
```

Comment: What Android version are you running and of which manufacturerm

Comment: Sony Ericsson Live With Walkman, OS Android 4.0.4 (Cyanogenmod 9.1.0)

Comment: could you try to do "adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/s.png" on your pc? If that doesn't work too itś  Sonys fault ;)

Comment: "adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/s.png" is working

Comment: Im sorry, it was my fault. Youre code is working. I just saw broken thumbnail of image and thought it's taking empty screenshot. But it isnt. It's normal. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer is working, please flag it as usefull and mark it solved. I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/s.png");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```