# Can an app take a screenshot while running in the background?

Tags: android, screenshot

Is it possible to programmatically take a screenshot of the screen while in a different app by some kind of a gesture in android? I want my app to run in background and when the user makes a particular gesture, I want my app(running in background to take a screen shot to be sent somewhere). I also want this gesture to recognize nearby devices that has my app to be able to get the screen shot for manipulation. I am still learning android, and I am planning this as my project. Just wanted to know if this is possible.

Comment: Possible for rooted devices

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android take screenshot on rooted device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965409/android-take-screenshot-on-rooted-device)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible 
check, there are many app on google play for this.

[Screenshot Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.screenshotultimate) and [Screenshot UX Trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liveov.shotuxtrial)