# How to convert .raw file to image file in android rooted device programmatically

Tags: java, android, bitmapimage

I am trying to create a screenshot capturing app in android which capture screen shot of device screen by using adb command programmatically. I have tried every link from stack overflow and other sites but not much successful yet. can any body help me out here. I have followed this link [Android take screenshot on rooted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965409/android-take-screenshot-on-rooted-device) to create the .raw file but now i am stuck on how to convert raw file to image in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android cannot do that by itself. You need a external decoder. There are libraries which can decode, demosaicing, whitebalance etc and convert to RGB. This is a digital negative and needs a lot of image processing before its viewable in Android.

Check out dcraw, its a library for decoding all types of RAW-files.

Comment: Well thanks for your reply but I have converted it via Bitmap factory using byte array of raw file

Answer (score 1):

if raw is image file then u can change extentention to jpg or png,

```
File ss = new File(ssDir, "ss.raw");
```

change this to

```
   File ss = new File(ssDir, "ss.jpg");
```

but capturing screenshots require root permission 
to execute su permission

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "screeshot.jpg");
Process localProcess  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream  os = localProcess .getOutputStream();
 //DataOutputStream  dos = (DataOutputStream) localProcess.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + f.toString()).getBytes("ASCII"));
//dos.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
os.close();
localProcess .waitFor();
```

Comment: os.writeBytes does not exist in OutputStream and my device has the root permissions butt this code just save black image and nothing else it just creates the image n ot get the screen shot and create it and simply changing the extension can also simply creates image because i am using this command /dev/graphics/fb0 to save framebuffer in raw form and then i need code or library which converts raw byte file to image file

Comment: this code works perfect on my kitkat but i don't know about you check your logcat issue and must add read write externel storage permission in manifest

Comment: I am testing this code on Android 2.3.5 but i will let you know if it works

Comment: By the way i have added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE butt which Read permissions are needed

Comment: Well that did not work either on my Android device. I just know if there is way to convert raw file to image.

Comment: if your device is rooted then open file manager go to system then bin then check there 'screencap' file exist??. btw i have tested it on 4.4.2

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have captured the image using frame buffer fb0 command